# How can I do this Mapping works

Tags: java, compiler-errors, mapping, mapper

please I'm not being able to make a simple Mapping struct between some classes in personal simple project. I have a simple Model class named Anime:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Anime {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
}
```

And I want, for example, to convert this class in a Dto response and convert a Dto request to Model as well. My Dto type classes are these below

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AnimePostReqDto {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AnimeRespDto {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

And finally this interface below is the Mapper:

```
import br.edu.devdojo2.app.dto.AnimePostReqDto;
import br.edu.devdojo2.app.dto.AnimeRespDto;
import br.edu.devdojo2.app.model.Anime;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface AnimeMapper {
    @Mapping(source = "reqDto.id", target = "id")
    @Mapping(source = "reqDto.name", target = "name")
    Anime toModel(AnimePostReqDto reqDto);

    @Mapping(source = "anime.id", target = "id")
    @Mapping(source = "anime.name", target = "name")
    AnimeRespDto toRespDto(Anime anime);
}
```

And the results when I build my project are:

```
Error:(15,11) java: The type of parameter "reqDto" has no property named "id".
Error:(15,11) java: The type of parameter "reqDto" has no property named "name".
Error:(19,18) java: The type of parameter "anime" has no property named "id".
Error:(19,18) java: The type of parameter "anime" has no property named "name".
```

Please, could somebody explain me why those errors above happen? Thanks.

Comment: You should put `lombok` annotation processor in your `pom`(if its maven project) before `mapstruct` processor